# REST web application foreign key issue

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, jboss, libcurl

I'm developing a RESTful web application, specs of which are as below:

1. two tables in the database, tableA and tableB.
2. tableA has columns named col1A and col2A
3. tableB has columns named col1B, col2B and col1A; this last column (col1A) being the foreign key, mapping into the primary key of tableA.

The JAVA classes corresponding to the tables are defined as:

```
class tableA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlTransient
    private int col1A;

    private string col2A;

    // getters and setters
}

class tableB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlTransient
    private int col1B;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "col1A", referencedColumnName = "col1A", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private tableA tableAObj;

    private string col2B;

    // getters and setters
    // There is a getter and setter for the col1A field as well.
}
```

Using libcurl, I send JSON objects to the above web application. One of the JSON objects (being sent to be persisted into the tableB) is of the form:

```
{
"col1A" : 1,               // assume this is the correct value of col1A
"col2B" : "col2BVal",
}
```

On sending the above JSON object to the web app, I get the following errors:

On libcurl side (I've enabled verbose in libcurl):

> Exception: N/A (through reference chain: com.package1.tableB["col1A"]). The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: com.package1.tableB["col1A"]))

On the web application:

> Failed executing POST /: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: com.package1.tableB["col1A"]).

The web application exception above was coming in the setter of col1A in the class tableB.

I removed the getter and setter for col1A (in class tableB) and then again sent the JSON object by using libcurl, only to receive the following errors:

On libcurl side:

> HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "col1A" (Class com.package1.tableB), not marked as ignorable.

On the web application:

> Unrecognized field "col1A" (Class com.package1.tableB), not marked as ignorable.

If anyone can help, thanks.

**EDIT**

The getter and setter functions for the col1A field in class tableB are defined as:

```
public int getCol1A() {
    return getTableA().getCol1A();
}

public void setCol1A(int Col1AVal) {
    getTableA().setCol1A(Col1AVal);
}
```

where getTableA() returns the tableAObj field of class tableB.

Answer (score 1):

I think the JSON should be something like this :

```
{
    "tableAObj" : { 
                  "col1A" : 1,               // assume this is the correct value of col1A
                  "col2A" : "value"
     },   
    "col2B" : "col2BVal"
}
```

Basically, the JSON for tableB should have a nested JSON for tableA.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to send some code snippets and info about the framework that you are using for RESTful webService.

Comment: I'm using RESTEasy with JBoss and Hibernate.
I don't want to send a nested JSON, I hope it won't be the only solution?

Comment: If sending the nested JSON object is not an option then you could define tableA's Id as a transient attribute (so that it is ignored by hibernate) in your tableB class and load the the child as soon as you receive the the parent object on the server side. I think your best option is to use 'Data Transfer Object' Pattern, wherein the structure of your the objects that you use for webservice interactions can be different from the Hibernate entities structure.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking along those lines as well; will have a look at that. Thanks.